# Is this a good way of Parsing JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

Im looking at another developers code that parses some JSON. I cant really see how it works or if its a good idea...

```
hmlPlaylist.prototype.loadVideos_callback = function (data) {
    var jsonData = '';
    var jsonError = false;

    try {
        jsonData = eval("(" + data + ")");
    } catch (jError) {
        jsonError = true;
    }

    if (!jsonError) {

        if (jsonData.playlists.length > 0) {
            this.buildPlaylistList(jsonData.playlists);
        }
        if (jsonData.videos.length > 0) {
            this.buildVideoList(jsonData.videos);
            this.bindVideoNavs();
        }
    }
    else {

        // no json returned, don't do anything
    }
};
```

Its the line

```
jsonData = eval("(" + data + ")");
```

That gets me. What does this do to the data? I thought you had to use an extarnal class library to parse JSON data?

I can see later on that he iterates the collection like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < playlistCount; i++) {

        var p = playlists[i];
```

So is this really a good way of going through JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most modern browsers support a native `JSON.parse` method that does exactly this. If you are targeting a browser that does not, you can use Douglas Crockford's implementation provided [here](http://www.json.org/js.html) (scroll to the bottom).

In any case, do not use `eval` if you can at all avoid it.

**Update** (regarding `eval`):

As [JSON.org](http://www.json.org/js.html) states:

> JSON is a subset of the object literal
>   notation of JavaScript. Since JSON is
>   a subset of JavaScript, it can be used
>   in the language with no muss or fuss.

What does this mean in practice? Well, it means that any valid JSON object is also valid JS code (in technical terms: it's a valid JS expression that evaluates to an object literal). Therefore, you can paste JSON into a file and tell e.g. your browser to load it as JavaScript and it will do so without any error or warning (of course the "JavaScript" won't actually *do* anything because it's just the representation of an object and not procedural code).

Since we established that JSON can be interpreted as JavaScript, it can also be passed to [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval). Let's see what the [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) has to say about `eval`:

> The argument of the eval function is a
>   string. If the string represents an
>   expression, eval evaluates the
>   expression.
>
> ...
>
> **Parsing JSON (converting strings to JavaScript objects)**
>
> If the string you're calling `eval()` on contains data (for example, an array: `"[1, 2, 3]"`), as opposed to code, you should consider switching to JSON, which allows the string to use a subset of JavaScript syntax to represent data.

The above is perhaps not the best explanation, but it does say what happens: JSON can be seen as a JS expression. `eval` takes a string representing a JS expression (in this case, a string containing JSON), evaluates it, and returns the result. It's like a mini-compiler that you can feed code to at runtime, and it will run the code for you and return the result. In this case, the result will be a JS object (as already mentioned, JSON is a valid JS expression that represents an object).

So if you have

```
var json = '{"foo": "bar", "answer": 42}';
var object1 = eval(json);

var object2 = { foo: "bar", answer: 42 };
```

Then `object1` and `object2` will be two different but identical objects.

Comment: I still dont get what eval does in this case? how can just wrapping something in brackets parse it?

Comment: @Pete2k: Just expanded the answer with a section on `eval`, check it out.

Comment: Cheers Jon, I like the bit about eval being a mini compiler, yeah that makes sense now!

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.parse(stringOfJson)` is the best way to parse json.  If you are using jquery, then you can tell `$.ajax` that you are expected json back, and it will parse it for you, with the `dataType: 'json'` configuration option

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that. Do this: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

One of the best recommended JSON parsers for Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

JSON is java script code.

`jsonData = eval("(" + data + ")");`

The `eval()` function is executing the java script code and return the result (the object). You can find some information about `eval` [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp).

The problem is, the `eval` function can also execute normal java script code, it's insecure. Use `JSON.parse(data)` instead.

Comment: ah right I see so basically its a javascript object notation being executed. So this is a good way of doing it right?

Comment: No it isn't a good way. The JSON can contain bad code that interact with the document. Use a save way like JSON.parse.

Answer (score 1):

`eval` just runs whatever string is supplied to it as though it were code. If you supply it JSON as a string, it evaluates the string as code, which then produces a JSON object. `eval` *is* legitimate for parsing JSON, although the argument for that has gotten considerably weaker these days as better methods exist (`JSON.parse`, jQuery's `$.ajax` with a `"json"` `datatype` or `$.getJSON`).

For an example of the argument `eval` accepts and what it produces:

```
var a = {foo: [0, 1], bar: {baz: 2}};
var b = JSON.stringify(a);
alert(b);                    // alerts '{"foo":[0,1],"bar":{"baz":2}}'
var c = eval("(" + b + ")");
alert(c.foo);                // alerts '0,1'
alert(c.bar.baz);            // alerts '2'
```

As for the safety of `eval`, as long as it can only accept well-formed JSON from *your* server that's not subject to user input, the risks are fairly minimal. The risk, FWIW, is that some user supplies JS code as a string that would inject a script, which could then be used to gather sensitive information on other users who visit the page. `JSON.parse` -- unless you're `eval`ing some of its contents afterwards -- wouldn't have this risk.